# Express.js: Use variables in route's path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a web application with MEAN stack and I want this scenario:

People can sign up and after that, They must have at least one `company` registered.
When they register a `company`, the base URL will be like these:

```
example.com/companyName/
example.com/companyName/members
example.com/companyName/settings
example.com/companyName/etc
```

So, my problem is, how can I use variables in my routes to match the user's registered company name?
Is it something like `app.use('/'+companyName, routes);` possible in `app.js`?

There is a piece of my code, just in case:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   console.log('going to '+companyUrl);
   next();
});

app.use('/'+companyUrl, routes);
```

I'm doing some works on other modules, and now, `noStartupRestrict.theStartupUrl` is **companyName** as it should be.
But the `app` is not using routes. it goes all the way down to 404 route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
app.use('/:companyName/something', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params.companyName);
  next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

app.js

```
...
var path = '/companyName';
app.use(path, routes);
...
```